# How to stop displaying printf of a particular C daemon in Linux

Tags: c, linux, terminal, console, printf

How can we stop displaying the `printf` output of a particular daemon on demand? By disabling a particular attribute, can I ignore `printf`?

Comment: You wrote the daemon, or at least have access to its sources and are willing to touch them? If not you are wrong here at SO.

Comment: Fair enough ... ;-) start it with redirecting `stdout` to the bit-bucket: `./a.out 1>/dev/null`

Comment: A program intended for use exclusively as a daemon ought not to be outputting anything to its `stdout`, nor, as far as it is within its control, to `stderr`.  Direct output to a log file, or log via syslog.